# Why is the magnetic field vector of light so weak compared to it’s electric field vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

As this article describes,
https://physics.aps.org/story/v26/st13
The magnetic field vector of light is extremely weak. It seems odd to me why this has never been explained in my science curriculum, considering how important the development of the theory of electromagnetism is.
Hence, what is the origin of this disparity in strength?

Comment: In Gaussian units the magnetic field of an EM wave is exactly as strong as the electric field.

Comment: In SI units they cannot even be compared because they don’t have the same units.

Comment: When charges move slowly compared to the speed of light, magnetic *forces* are weak compared with electric forces. Electrons in atoms are non-relativistic.

Answer (score 2):

It's not fair to compare $E$ and $B$ (They have a different units). Consider the energy density associated with them (considering monochromatic waves and take average and all)
$$u_B=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ u_E=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2$$
$$\frac{u_B}{u_E}=\frac{B^2}{E^2}c^2$$
Further $E=cB\Rightarrow u_B=u_E.$